# Meaning of the notation $\ll$, as in $ |\zeta(\sigma+it)|\ll\left(\frac{t}{2\pi}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}-\sigma} $

Tags: notation

In number theory I often see the notation $\ll$ intuitively meaning "way smaller". I first though it had the same meaning as $o$ but then I came accross expressions like
$$ |\zeta(\sigma+it)|\ll\left(\frac{t}{2\pi}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}-\sigma} $$
for $\sigma<0$. There, there are $2$ parameters involved : $\sigma$ and $t$ so the $o$ analogy doesn't apply there, except if $\sigma$ is fixed. But even if $\sigma$ is fixed we don't know wheter it should be $$\underset{t\rightarrow+\infty}{o} \qquad \text{or} \qquad \underset{t\rightarrow -\infty}{o},$$ or even something else. That's why I'm asking what is the definition of $\ll$ and how can it be used. For instance does $f(x,y)\ll g(x,y)$ is as allowed as $u_n\ll v_n$.

Comment: It is $O$ not $o$ meaning just $|f| \le C|g|$ as $|t| \to \infty$ Here $C$ depends on $\sigma$ but can be taken uniform for $\sigma$ in a compact set; the result is just the functional equation, the boundness of zeta on $\sigma > 1$ (for fixed $\sigma$ or uniform in a compact set of them) and the asymptotics of the multiplier (essentially a gamma factor and a trigonometric one) at infinite imaginary

Comment: Maybe I'm ignorant, but I've only seen $\ll$ used as $O$. I have heard once that people sometimes use it as $o$, but I've never actually encountered that.

Comment: Well that makes sense, thank you all !